# How does this function find the value of another variable?

Tags: python, scope

Here is the code:

```
def caller(callee):
    callee()

def wrapper():

    def a():
        print v0

    for i in range(5):
        v0 = i*i
        caller(a)

wrapper()
```

The above code outputs:

```
0
1
4
9
16
```

But I don't understand how `a` resolves the variable `v0`.  I can not find the related python docs regarding this language feature.

Comment: Here is some reading material about this: https://realpython.com/blog/python/inner-functions-what-are-they-good-for/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using global variables in a function other than the one that created them](//stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them)

Comment: @Zizouz212 There are no global variables in this code (other than the functions `wrapper` and `caller`).  Specifically, `v0` is not global.

Comment: @TomKarzes Eh, true, now that I think about it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scope of variables defined in a function includes all the nested functions within it. So variables defined in `wrapper()` are accessible within `a()`, because this function is nested in it. This is known as *lexical scoping*, and it's often used in creating closures.

This is explained in the Python [Resolution of Names](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/executionmodel.html#resolution-of-names) documentation:

> A *scope* defines the visibility of a name within a block. If a local variable is defined in a block, its scope includes that block. If the definition occurs in a function block, the scope extends to any blocks contained within the defining one, unless a contained block introduces a different binding for the name.

Answer (score 1):

The function `a` is defined per invocation of `wrapper`.  When a given instance of `a` is called, it looks up `v0` within the context of its definition, which is the specific call to `wrapper` that defined it.  By the time `a` has been called, `v0` has been defined within `wrapper`, and `a` uses that definition of `v0`.

In this example, the invocation of `wrapper` that defines `a` is still active when `a` is called, but it need not be.  In other words, `wrapper` could return, and a reference to `a` from that context could still be called.  In this case it would be a closure.  But that does not occur in this example.

Here's an example that does use closures:

```
def foo(x):
    def bar():
        return x
    return bar

f1 = foo(123)
f2 = foo(456)

print(f1())
print(f2())
```

The output is:

```
123
456
```

When `foo` is called, it returns an instance of `bar` which evaluates `x` in the context in which `foo` was called.  In the first invocation `x` is 123, and in the second it is `456`.  Those bindings persist even after the calls to `foo` have returned.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that all code in a function is not run until the function is called.  By the time `a()` is called, `v0` has been defined in an outer scope, so it can recognize the variable and evaluate it.